# I'm trying to accept a backspace input as a character

Tags: visual-studio, basic

I'm writing a program in visual basic 2015 to add users to the school server.  I have text box's, that aren't editable, to display input from other text boxes.  Sounds more complicated than it is, but the text boxes simply show your entries, so a lot will be completed without having to double up on entries.  As the input changes on an input textbox, it updates to the display.  However, I cannot detect a backspace input to update the displayed content.  Is there a way to do this?
Here's a sample of the code.

```
Private Sub dp_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dp.TextChanged
        If dp.Text = "" Then GoTo line1
        i = Asc(dp.Text)
        If i = 8 Then
            domainp.Text = domainp.Text.Remove(domainp.Text.Length - 1)
        End If
        If dp.Text = "" Or dp.Text = " " Or dp.Text = "." Then GoTo line1
        domainp.Text = domainp.Text & dp.Text
        domain_prefix = domainp.Text
        dp.Text = ""
        i = 0
line1:
    End Sub
```

I haven't programmed for years and have forgotten a LOT of things.  I would appreciate any help you could give me.

I am using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyDown event.  This will capture any type, backspace, or arrow key movement.